# Why does UnitCount differ between PackageInfoTable and TPackageTypeInfo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, internals

If you put a breakpoint in `System._StartExe` and examine the InitTable that gets passed in, you'll notice that `InitTable.UnitCount` is greater than `InitTable.TypeInfo.UnitCount`.  Unfortunately, neither of these records are documented very well.  Does anyone know what these two numbers represent and why they're different?  I assume InitTable.UnitCount is the total number of units in the application.  But what's the other one?

Comment: UnitCount tells how many entries are in the accompanying UnitInfo table. I assume TypeInfo.UnitCount corresponds to something similar. Can you compare those two tables to see how their contents differ?

Comment: @Rob: Not really. The two tables show different sets of data about their respective units, with no overlap as near as I can tell.  The first table doesn't even include unit names, which makes me wonder where programs like DeDe were extracting them from in EXEs compiled pre-D2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that
- `PackageInfoTable.UnitCount` counts the units stored in the `UnitInfo` array, where each record holds the initalization and finalization code pointers for the units parts of the package.
- `PackageInfoTable.TypeInfo.UnitCount` along with ...`UnitNames` references the Units containing some `TypeInfo` stored in the `TypeTable` (real Type Info or unit boundary marker).

A unit can contain some Init/Finit code but no TypeInfo to gather and reciprocally, hence the difference...

FYI, look at `procedure ChangeFinalizationsOrder` in [MemCheck.pas](http://v.mahon.free.fr/pro/freeware/memcheck/) to see how they hack the InitTable (up to D2006)...